# Pipe Under Dryer

Tags: plumbing, pipe, dryer, washer, laundry

While remodeling my place I ran into a random pipe under my dryer. What is the for? I had to cut out a square in the metal floor and when I pulled it out, it turned out to be a pipe. I don't think anything is/was connected to it. Should I be worried?

[Here's some pictures](https://imgur.com/gallery/CtnTgK9)

Comment: It is in the bad size range, of being a very small drain pipe or a large supply pipe.  Unused drain pipes can be connected to the sewers, so it should be capped off to prevent sewer gas from coming up.

Comment: Could even be for gas for a gas dryer.

Comment: Looks to me as though that might have once been a lead sheet shower pan. Of if not a shower pan, maybe just a floor drain for underneath the laundry area.

Comment: Why did you cut this out without knowing what it was? It may have been a useful drain in case of a water leak.